# How to print samples/observations/rows of any one cluster using scikit learn/pandas/python?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mean-shift

Very basic question:

How do I print the observations attributed to any one cluster?

```
data = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
X = data[['Var1','Var2','Var3']]
ms = MeanShift()
ms.fit(X)
labels = ms.labels_
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_
```

I'd just like to see the values of 'Var1','Var2','Var3' for any one cluster.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to view the predictions for your dataset. This can be done as follows:

```
y_pred = ms.predict(X)
```

You could then link these up to your samples by doing this:

```
df['y_pred'] = y_pred
```

And filter your dataframe as desired, e.g. to see the samples in cluster 1:

```
df[df.y_pred == 1]
```

Comment: Great, I think that's it!